# How to link django custom user model and django allauth package

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I have a custom user model in django made using AbstractUser. I am using the django allauth package for my authentication. I have made custom fields in both but am unable to link both of them.

**models.py**

```
from django.db import models
from django.conf import settings
from django.shortcuts import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

class User(AbstractUser):
    age = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=30,blank=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from .models import User
class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):

    first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name')
    last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name')
    age = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Age')
    phone = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Phone Number')
    address = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Address')
    gender = forms.CharField(max_length=30,label = 'Gender')
    print('FN',first_name)
    print('Age',age)

    def signup(self, request, user):
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.age = self.cleaned_data['age']
        user.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        user.address = self.cleaned_data['address']
        user.gender = self.cleaned_data['gender']
        user.save()
        return user
```

I have defined a customUserAdmin

**admin.py**

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Medicine,Order,OrderItem,Pharmacy,Address
from django.contrib.auth.admin import UserAdmin
from .models import User
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model


class CustomUserAdmin(UserAdmin):
    """Define admin model for custom User model with no username field."""
    fieldsets = (
        (None, {'fields': ('email', 'password')}),
        (_('Personal info'), {'fields': ('first_name', 'last_name','age','phone','address','gender')}),
        (_('Permissions'), {'fields': ('is_active', 'is_staff', 'is_superuser',
                                       'groups', 'user_permissions')}),
        (_('Important dates'), {'fields': ('last_login', 'date_joined')}),
    )
    add_fieldsets = (
        (None, {
            'classes': ('wide',),
            'fields': ('email', 'password1', 'password2'),
        }),
    )
    list_display = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name', 'is_staff')
    search_fields = ('email', 'first_name', 'last_name')
    ordering = ('email',)
admin.site.register(get_user_model(), CustomUserAdmin)
```

I have registered my custom user model in settings.py using

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'core.User'
```

In both the django allauth signup page and the custom user model the fields are shown. But when I signup and add values in the custom fields they are not stored in the user model in the database. I am unable to link the signup page and user model.

[image: My custom signup page]

[image: Custom user field in admin]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Django version 3.1.7

Here is a way to save the user's type to database record

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from allauth.account.forms import SignupForm
from .models import User

class MyCustomSignupForm(SignupForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MyCustomSignupForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='First Name')
        last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Last Name')
        age = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Age')
        phone = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Phone Number')
        address = forms.CharField(max_length=30, label='Address')
        gender = forms.CharField(max_length=30,label = 'Gender')

    # Put in custom signup logic
    def custom_signup(self, request, user):
        # Set the user's type from the form reponse
        user.first_name = self.cleaned_data['first_name']
        user.last_name = self.cleaned_data['last_name']
        user.age = self.cleaned_data['age']
        user.phone = self.cleaned_data['phone']
        user.address = self.cleaned_data['address']
        user.gender = self.cleaned_data['gender']

        # Save the user's type to their database record
        user.save()
```

and if it's not worked, look at this:
https://dev.to/danielfeldroy/customizing-django-allauth-signup-forms-2o1m